# How could I process activity with CloudAdapter without request object

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

We are currently using `botframeworkAdapter.processActivityDirect` to process MS Teams activity from webhook. However, botframeworkAdapter is deprecated and it is recommended to move to [CloudAdapter](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/blob/main/libraries/botbuilder/src/cloudAdapter.ts#L46).

I'm having trouble figuring out how to migrate to CloudAdapter because it seems like there isn't a way to process activity without http request and response object. We are processing activity asynchronously through job queues and workers so we don't have access to the original request.

BotframeworkAdapter allows this through [`processActivityDirect`](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/blob/main/libraries/botbuilder/src/botFrameworkAdapter.ts#L1305). Wondering if there is a way to achieve this somehow with `CloudAdapter`. I made a feature request in botbuilder-js repo but just asking in case anyone has ideas.

[`CloudAdapter.process`](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/blob/main/libraries/botbuilder/src/cloudAdapter.ts#L86) seems to be the only way to process activity, which seems limited number of options compare to `BotframeworkAdapter`.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is being addressed here - https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/issues/4349 where a PR has been raised to Add new method to expose same functionality as BotFrameworkAdapter.processActivityDirect.